# Recommended way to include remote javascript library in Ember.JS ember-cli App

Tags: ember.js

What is the proper way to include a javascript library in my Ember app that exists on another server? To make this tangible, I'm trying to include a Salesforce JS library that my Ember app will use, but I want the client browser to pull the Salesforce JS directly from Salesforce as I believe the file is subject to change (bug fixes, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply import the file as you would any other JavaScript library and simply specify the hosted URL in the script tag.  Ember will have access to the library the same as any other JavaScript you would write.

```
<script src="//path/to/salesforce/js/file"></script>
```